# completely messed up my android studio app's package setup

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, package

my android studio app package setup is all messed up and when I try to compile my app 
it cannot find my MainActivity class
What happened is when I first imported my project from eclipse it made all my source folders into different packages so I got rid of the packages and made them just regular source dirs.
my hierarchy is now like this

```
TestApp/app/src/main/java/
TestApp/app/src/main/java/Base
TestApp/app/src/main/java/Adapters
TestApp/app/src/main/java/Interfaces
```

and has no packages at all just regular java src dirs

there is no root package directory anymore and I don't know how to put one back in. Please help!

PS: here is the full error that comes up

```
 Unexpected error: Error: Activity class {com.L33TRUS.TestApp/MainActivity} does not exist.
```

my MainActivity.java file is inside the TestApp/app/src/main/java/Base/ folder

Comment: yes thanks. I replied ages ago but somehow it never submitted I'm sorry. I just re created my project and made all the source folders "packages" thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `TestApp/app/src/main/java/` as a source directory in your IDE.

The `MainActivity` should declare `package Base;` at the top.
The other classes too should declare their package correctly,
relative from the source directory root (`TestApp/app/src/main/java/`).